# Insert Custom Page between 2 sections in NSIS

Tags: nsis

(I am sorry I couldn't come up with a better title)

I have the following partial-code:

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
Page Custom nsDialogsPage nsDialogsPageLeave

section Section1
#do something
sectionEnd

section Section2
#do something else
sectionEnd

Function nsDialogsPage
#do something
FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogsPageLeave
#do something else
FunctionEnd
```

But, now I want the Custom Page to show up after Section1 and before Section2 (I Enter some info in the custom page which is used in Section2). How should I go about this ? (I can always put the Custom Page before MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES, but that looks rather odd for the user.)

Comment: It is pretty common for installers to collect as much information as possible before starting the actual install steps that make changes to the system, why do you think it is a good idea to split up the install progress like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All sections are executed on the instfiles page, it is however possible to have multiple instfiles pages. To prevent all sections from executing twice you need to turn the correct sections on/off with the helper macros in `sections.nsh` or store some state in a global variable and put all the sections code inside a if block, ex:`${If} $installstep = 0`. You might also need to use `SetAutoClose`...

Comment: Thanks,I tried the Global variable idea, which worked!  However the code looks really messy :)

Answer (score 0):

I used a PRE Function to select/unselect sections:

```
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

    !define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE checkSkipSection
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
    Page Custom nsDialogsPage nsDialogsPageLeave
    !define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE checkSkipSection
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

    Var SkipSection

    section Section1
    #do something
    StrCpy $SkipSection 1
    sectionEnd

    section Section2
    #do something else
    sectionEnd

    Function nsDialogsPage
    #do something
    FunctionEnd

    Function nsDialogsPageLeave
    #do something else
    FunctionEnd

Function checkSkipSection

    ${If} $SkipSection = ""
         SectionSetFlags ${Section1} ${SF_SELECTED}
         SectionSetFlags ${Section2} 0

    ${ElseIf} $SkipSection = 1
         SectionSetFlags ${Section2} ${SF_SELECTED}
         SectionSetFlags ${Section1} 0

    ${EndIf}

FunctionEnd
```

So in the 1st MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES, only Section1 is run, while Section2 is run in the 2nd MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES page.

Comment: Or if you dont want to use the SkipSection variable, use two separate Functions checkSkipSection1 and 2 for the Custom Pages, and set the flags accordingly in each.